# Accessing element buried many layers deep in Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm new to Xpath, and I'm trying to get the following element from [this site](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance) using the Scrapy Python library:

```
<a ui-sref="app.releasenotedetail({ locale: activeLocale, releasenoteId:note.id})" class="ng-binding x-hidden-focus" href="/en-us/security-guidance/releasenotedetail/253dc509-9a5b-e911-a98e-000d3a33c573">June 2019 Security Updates</a>
```

I've tried it using descendant notation:

```
release_url = response.xpath("//a[@class='ng-binding x-hidden focus']").extract()
```

I've tried it by copying the XPath from the element directly from the dev console:

```
release_url = response.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/ui-view/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a").extract()
```

Neither works. `release_url` comes up blank. How can I get to this element? What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried this `//a[contains(.,'June 2019 Security Updates')]`

Answer (score 1):

This element is loaded with extra POST-request to `https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/api/security-guidance/en-us/releaseNotes`. Check it on screenshot:

[image: webinspector]

So, make same POST-request with same headers and payload and you will get json with needed data.